# SCCM/MECM - Task Sequence - Run command "as a different account" issues

Tags: task, sequence, sccm, runas

I'm here today to talk about a MECM task sequence I'm having a problem with.

**Context:**
The idea is to make the TS available in the software center so that the process can be launched by a user from his active session by collecting some informations about him.
The TS collects the information from the current user/domain and then launches a powershell script using an account with specific rights in a command line.
The user/session parameters will be used in the script.

Informations are collected with the "quser" command.

**Problem:**
The problem I encounter today is that whatever account I want to use to launch the command line, the step is failing.

The logs show that the file (the ps1 script) is not found.
The error is the same if I indicate the full path to the file.
I tried to use the -session: option from serviceUI.exe (collected with "quser" command) but it still does not work.

**Command line used:**
serviceui.exe -process:TSProgressUI.exe -session:%CurrentUserSessionID% %windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "*scriptpath*.ps1" -User "%userVAR%" -Domain "%userDomainVAR%"

Any idea or suggestion ?

Comment: I am really confused as to what you want to actually accomplish. If you want to run a PS script why would you use serviceui.exe and not call powershell.exe in a "run command line" step? Be that as it may, the -File parameter of powershell.exe expects a real existing powershell file "*.ps1" is wildcard syntax for some sort of search maybe but not a full path to a script file, so this would not work from the commandline and thus also not from a TS

Comment: Hey Syberdoor thanks for your comment. **About the *.ps1** : i just dont write the script full path on stack but i use the full path in the command line.
**Serviceui.exe** is used to display the GUI of the script so users can interact with it

Comment: We only use for OSD so I am not 100% about it but if I specify a run command line step there, user can interact with it (although they never should, because it will lead to timeouts), so I would recommend at least for testing to just do the exact same commandline that works for you (with the exact same user) outside of a TS. If that works you can slowly add more complexity like serviceui.exe (if you find it even necessary). Also if it is a short script I would recommend the -NoExit parameter for powershell.exe so you can see your errors or "Start-Transript" in the script